# Start process in high priority

Tags: windows, cpu, process

When windows starts I see most of the processes start in normal priority. I can manually change the priority of a running process. But what I want is when a particular process starts it be automatically set to run in high priority.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 14):

You can start a process in high proirity in command line. Use the `start` command.

> start ["title"] [/dPath] [/i] [/min] [/max] [{/separate | /shared}] [{/low | /normal | /high | /realtime | /abovenormal | belownormal}] [/wait] [/b] [FileName] [parameters]

eg:- `start "Explorer" /high "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"`
For easy access type this into a notepad and save as file with "bat" extension. Then you only have to double click [this file](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: I understand we can definitely set priority using command line. But what I want it to to automate the process, and no user action needs to be required. I am thinking that I can store the .bat file somewhere and tell windows to execute it automatically at logon. Does it make correct sense?

Comment: How do you call it when you want to do it at login @BishnuD.? I'd commend you call this entire process instead of just the process you want to start.... so `start "whateverthisis#" /high /path/to/the/executable`

Answer (score 1):

Try somethinglike this win HCKU current version run:

```
cmd /c start "Google Sync" /belownormal "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" /autostart
```

Answer (score -5):

Right click and drag the file to the startup folder under the start menu, and create a shortcut there. Windows automatically runs anything under the startup menu upon logon.

Comment: The question was rather how to start process in high priority, not how to start it upon logon.