# Start process in realtime priority

Tags: windows-10, python, priority

This is a follow-up on this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/699651/start-process-in-high-priority)

I need to start a process with the realtime priority.

```
start "my_script.py" /realtime "Z:\location\of\python\script"
```

doesn't result in realtime priority. It sets it to high. Both commands `/high` and `/realtime` do the same.

why doesn't it work?

[task manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW2J8.jpg)

Comment: Does your account have permission to run at Realtime? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009502/how-to-start-executable-with-realtime-priority

Comment: Indeed I wasn't running the command line as administrator. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal users only have permissions to elevate as far as `/high`. They do not have the ability to raise a processes priority to `/realtime`.

In order to raise a processes priority to `/realtime` one must have administrative rights and use these for the elevation.

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009502/how-to-start-executable-with-realtime-priority