# Use Start-Process to start a process with high priority

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I have seen [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1328931/start-process-in-realtime-priority) but I want to use `Start-Process` to start a .exe file with higher priority. Is this possible? Or should I combine `Start` and `Start-Process` in some tricky way? Command under consideration:

```
Start-Process `
    -FilePath "C:\Program Files\binary.exe" `
    -ArgumentList "-n $($Env:ComputerName.ToLower())" `
    -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Comment: Does [Launch process with priority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053255/3536342) answer your question?

Comment: You can even do it from a simple CMD: `wmic process where name="process_name" CALL setpriority n`, where *n* is shown at https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/change-priority-of-win10-process-with-command-line/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the priority of the process after it's started by
[Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3).

By default `Start-Process` returns no output, so you need to use
the `-PassThru` parameter for it to return the Process object.

Setting the
[Priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processpriorityclass?view=net-8.0)
of the process object :

```
($Process = Start-Process ... -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal
```

An alternative is using the
[SetPriorityClass function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setpriorityclass):

```
$Process = Start-Process ... -PassThru
Set-ProcessPriority -ProcessId $Process.id -Priority AboveNormal
```